Expanding a periodic function in powers of sine
Question 7.12 of Whittaker and Watson's $\textit{A Course of Modern Analysis}$ asks to show that a function $f$, periodic with period $2\pi$ subject to certain analycity conditions, can be expanded in a series of the form
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \sin^nx + \cos x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \sin^nx \hspace{1cm} (1) $$
within some region of the complex plane. Suppose for simplicity that we are only working with real-valued functions and that we consider the series only in the formal sense. I am wondering if there is some nice formula for the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$, something resembling the formula for the Fourier coefficients of a function. I tried using Fourier's theorem to expand the function in the form
$$ f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin(nx) \hspace{1cm} (2) $$ and then replacing the trigonometric terms with Chebyshev polynomials, but rearranging the resulting series to obtain $(1)$ gives the $A_n$ and $B_n$ in terms of infinite series involving the Fourier coefficients. Similarly expanding the $\sin^nx$ terms in (finite) Fourier series in $(1)$ and comparing with $(2)$ does not allow one to find the $A_n$ and $B_n$ in terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$. Is there another way to go about this?

First of all, $f(\pi - x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \sin^n(x) - \cos(x) \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \sin^n(x)$, so this reduces to finding the coefficients in
$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \sin^n(x)$. Now
$g(\arcsin(z)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n z^n$ for $-\pi/2 \le z \le \pi/2$ is an ordinary Maclaurin series, so if $h(z) = g(\arcsin(z))$, $A_n = h^{(n)}(0)/n!$.

Thanks, but how does one find the coefficients of in terms of $g^{(n)}(0)$ now? Burmann's theorem gives the formula $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} \frac{g'(x) x^n}{\sin^nx} $$ but there seems no way to simplify this

You can use Faa di Bruno's formula for the $n$'th derivative of a composite function, but it'll be rather messy.
